# Nginx will rewirte image domain http to https, But I don't want the static server as https

Tags: wordpress, nginx

I have a wordpress website with https protocol by configuring the nginx 301 redirect:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  xxx.com;
    return       301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen       443 ssl;
    server_name  xxx.com;
    ssl_certificate     conf.d/xxx.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key conf.d/xxx.key;
}
```

And my article has some image links with static server like:
http://yyy.com/1.png

But when i access this article: it will be https://yyy.com/1.png, How do I configure the nginx that can still use http for the image static server?

Comment: Well a HTTPS site should even serve static content over https and not http. So you shouldn't actually do that

Comment: For security purpose, I think so. but I just want to know how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You would do that using below config

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  xxx.com;
    location ~* \.(png|ico|jpeg)$ {
       root <your root folder>;
       try_files $uri =404;
    }

    location / {
       return       301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
    }
}

server {
    listen       443 ssl;
    server_name  xxx.com;
    ssl_certificate     conf.d/xxx.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key conf.d/xxx.key;
}
```

Comment: Make sure you test in a incognito browser